# function for gouping in jupyter notebook

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, django-models, jupyter-notebook, django-views

i am having issues running this code

df_group_one= df[['drive-wheels','body-style','price']]

df_grouped_one= df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean()
df_group_one

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 df_grouped_one= df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean()
2 df_group_one

NameError: name 'df_group_one' is not defined

df_group_one = df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean()
df_group_one

Answer (score 0):

you misstyped the variable. It should be

```
import pandas as pd
path='https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/automobileEDA.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path)
df_group_one= df[['drive-wheels','body-style','price']]
print(df_group_one)
```

Comment: i still received same message

Comment: it shows errors      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[63], line 1
----> 1 df_grouped_one= df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean() 
      2 df_grouped_one

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm assuming you're using automobileEDA.csv. 
I edited my response for the working code that I tried.